# Run-time SVG error but not in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I have loaded sucessfully a SVG file into Android Studio using the New -> Vector Asset, the SVG file imports fine.

I can add an imageView and reference the SVG, inside Android studio it renders fine.

[image]

When I run the app, at run time I get an error;

```
 PID: 7369
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class ImageView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class ImageView
```

I have done everything I would have to other svg's so that its usable, I've never came across this error with an svg before.

The fragment / ImageView code is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="263dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arabicflag"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="43dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="397dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Stack Trace is below;

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: uk.co.futsalselect.app.futsalselect, PID: 7369
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class ImageView
              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class ImageView
              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable uk.co.futsalselect.app.futsalselect:drawable/ic_arabicflag with resource ID #0x7f070088
              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_arabicflag.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070088
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                  at uk.co.futsalselect.app.futsalselect.tournament_fragment.onCreateView(tournament_fragment.java:21)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path string cannot be empty.
                  at android.util.PathParser.nCreatePathDataFromString(Native Method)
                  at android.util.PathParser.-wrap1(PathParser.java)
                  at android.util.PathParser$PathData.<init>(PathParser.java:74)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1556)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1507)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:693)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:598)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
                    ... 33 more
```

The image file is too big to paste here.

Has anyone experienced an svg being successfully imported and causing errors at runtime? And what did you do to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the xml layout?

Comment: The layout file or the image XML (the XML for the flag is sizable)?

Comment: The xml layout is fine, but can you share the whole layout? Also please add the full stack trace, there are probably more informations to understand the error

Comment: I've updated the question with all of the code for the fragment and the stack trace output. Thanks.

Comment: what is the size of the svg image?

Comment: In which android version are you running it?

Comment: The size is 620kb, the version of Android I'm targeting is API 24 (though running it on a API 26 on my Galaxy S8 still doesn't work)

Comment: seems like the file has been placed in wrong folder . Share folder location of the drawable image

Comment: The file is in res -> drawable

Comment: The error seems caused by `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_arabicflag.xml`, do you have the file in the drawable folder? If the file is there try with the [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468232/3789527)

Comment: try to remove tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="43dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="397dp". and use android:src instadeof app:srcCompat

Comment: I've tried both and no joy. I also found this and the edit looks interesting; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710851/android-nougat-cannot-show-certain-vector-files-resourcesnotfoundexception